# What does "one of" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

[As Kim Ends Beijing Visit, China and North Korea Craft New Messages](https://www.nytimes.com/2018/06/20/world/asia/china-north-korea-kim-visit.html)

> Mr. Kim's father, Kim Jong-il, also visited the agricultural research
>   institution while he ruled North Korea, in 2006, **one of** more than two
>   dozen factories and plants he inspected during seven trips to China.

Maybe it means "one of his 7 trips"?
That means, one of his 7 trips, he inspected more than 2 dozen factories and plants?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means one of the two dozen factories, which he has inspected during his seven trips to China. So, it refers to the factory and not the trips. This sentence is about the fact, that both Kim Jong-il and Kim Jong-un visited the same factory/institution.